# Cannot sigin in using Firebase Auth from release apk (no Google Play)

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to login in Android app using Firebase Auth (phone).

It **works perfectly** when in **debug apk**.

But it **does not work** if the **apk is signed** (using the signature.jks file). and says : `"Unknown error"` in phone after input of phone number.

I looked through different question in Stack Overflow too but they suggest to add **SHA key to playstore console.** But that does not make sense. What if I want to publish the apks in amazon market or other android app market? Firebase forbids that?

Is there any solution to it? I must be missing a tiny point but I am lost to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add SHA-1 fingerprint of your release key to Google Play Console. But, to enable Firebase Authentication, you need to add it in Firebase Console. Follow the steps given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).

Answer (score 0):

I am coming right now from solving this issue.

Each playstores impose their own SHA1 and SHA256 key. So grab that and go to your firebase console and add it there.

Voila it will work!!